# HelpProvider in web application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, msdn

Q:

Can i use the **HelpProvider**
   control in a web application like
   windows application,,if not what are
   the alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can i use the HelpProvider control in a web application ?

No, it is a WinForms control and won't work in a Web App.

> if not what are the alternatives?

Take a look around on the WWW for an example. You will find a few "icon next to control" ideas where a small symbol provides more explanation when clicked.

But usually a designer will try to prevent the need for them a s much as possible.

Also note that there is no "F1=Help" convention or support on the web.